# Read doesn't seems to block until something is written to a pipe in a program using fork

Tags: c

Basically I know how to solve the program so that it does what it's suppose to do correctly(which is calculating the multiplication times 10 of a number entered by the user) by adding `wait` and `kill`, but I don't understand why it doesn't work as it is. I though the `read` were blocking but in this case, it seems the `read` don't block since they don't seem to wait for entries in the pipe. The `read` of the parents should block until there is a value inside.

Here is the program I'm talking about, why does the entry 1 returns 1 instead of 10? In what order are applied the system call in that case? Is this because the `read` of the parent reads pfd[1] while var is written in the pipe before the `write` of the child as the time to take place? I thought the `read` of the child would clean what is in the pipe before the `read` of the parent take place.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int multi(int var) {
   int multi;
   int pfd[2];
   pipe(pfd);
   int pid = fork();
   if (pid>0) {
       write(pfd[1], &var, sizeof(var));
       read(pfd[0], &multi, sizeof(multi));
       close(pfd[0]);
   } else {
       read(pfd[0], &var, sizeof(var));
       multi = 10 * var;
       write(pfd[1], &multi, sizeof(multi));
       close(pfd[1]);
   }
   return multi;
}

int main(void) {
   int x;
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", &x);
   printf("%d\n", multi(x));
}
```

Comment: The posted code is ignoring all of the return-values of the functions it calls.  If you don't pay attention to the return-values, you have no way of knowing whether the function succeeded or failed, and also no way of knowing *why* the function failed if it did fail (which is probably the info you need to answer your question).  For the functions above, you generally want to check to see if the return-value is -1, and if it is, you can check `errno` to see what the error was (or for quick debugging, just call `perror("blah")` to have a human-readable error string printed to your console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution of the parent and child is unpredictable. If the parent executes its `read(pfd[0])` before the child does, it will simply read what it just wrote. Adding a call to `wait()` ensures that the parent won't try to read from the pipe until after the child has read and written the reply.

Another solution is to use two pipes, one for parent->child communication, and another for child->parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will improve the program but I was just wondering why right now, when I enter 1 there is only 1 output. Shouldn't there be two output since two process are created by the fork? Is it because the read of the child block since the parent close it before it as time to read anything?

Comment: If the parent reads the pipe first, the child blocks in `read()` forever, since there's nothing else for it to read. So it never returns from `multi()` and never executes `printf()`.

Comment: This confirm what I taught. I will ask a last question. Does the child process at this point becomes a zombie, or does it stays in a blocked state after the parent as exited? Or it simply become orphan? Because when I look at the running process, my process is still running after it's execution.

Comment: It becomes an orphan and stays in the blocked state. It will become a child of PID 1.